# Vue js displaying nothing

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

I'm trying to load the data for a site from a database using Vue.js. Everything looks nice...the Vue.js data works ok in the console but on the page appears nothing. I'm pretty sure it's not about how I access it because in the console it works fine. Have you any idea what could have gone wrong? 
Many Thanks!

[console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMKjs.png)

html

```
            <div id="featured">
            {{featured[0].list_featured_text}}
            </div>
```

javascript

```
        var topArticle=new Vue({
        el:'#featured',
        data:{featured:null},
        created: function(){
                    $.get("featured.php",function(data){
                      this.featured=JSON.parse(data);
                      console.log(this.featured);
                                                        }
                          );
                        }
        });
```

php

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$passwort="";
$port=3306;
$databname="futurezone";
$conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$passwort,$databname,$port);
if($conn->connect_error)
die("Connection failed. ". $conn->conn->error);
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

$sql="SELECT * FROM featured";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Connection failed.")

$myarray=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$myarray[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($myarray);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("featured.php", function(data) {
    this.featured = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(this.featured);
});
```

`this` inside the callback function is not the same as `this` outside this function.
To preserve `this` - use fat-arrow function `() => {}` or use an inremediate variable like `self`, for example:

```
$.get("featured.php", (data) => {
    this.featured = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(this.featured);
});
```

or

```
let self = this;
$.get("featured.php", function(data) {
    self.featured = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(self.featured);
});
```